# Bash command to get list of directories

Tags: bash

I'd like to know the command to get a list of the current directories in a directory which satisfies the following conditions:

- It excludes hidden directories
- Directories with spaces are not broken up into multiple entries
- Files (and hidden files) are not included in the list

(I intend to iterate over this list in a bash script)

Comment: use a glob expression: `*/` -- e.g. `for d in */; do ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this for listing:

```
shopt -u dotglob
printf "%s\n" */
```

`shopt -u dotglob` makes sure to not to match hidden directories.

To iterate you can do:

```
for d in */; do
    echo "${d%/}"
done
```

Comment: my problem with 'd in */;' is that i get a trailing slash at the end of every name - how can i avoid this?

Comment: check updated answer. `echo "${d%/}"` will strip last `/`

Answer (score -1):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 ! -name '.*' -type d
```

Matches all your needs